# HTML5 video tag always gives Invalid source

Tags: html, video

Here is my code:

```
<video width="400" controls>
                              <source src="d:/lscweb/Presentations/2015-04-07 Ampersand.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>
```

But when I load up the page I get "Aborted" in the video player. If I do this:

```
<video width="400" controls>
                              <source src="d:/lscweb/Presentations/2015-04-07 Ampersand.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                              <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                              Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
                            </video>
```

I get "Invalid source". I assume it's trying to look up the mov_bbb.ogg file which doesn't exist. But I want it to play the first one. It's mp4. Why won't it play?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use link references to absolute windows os paths.

I suggest you move the video to the same folder as your html document and just do src="video.mp4" to avoid needing to use complex relative paths.

Comment: Still get Invalid Source.